# Problems compiling Sass - sass input.scss output.css "Error reading input.scss: no such file or directory."

Tags: css, npm, sass

I've successfully installed sass with

```
sudo npm install -g sass
```

I attempt to complile sass to css by running

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

But I get the error "Error reading input.scss: no such file or directory."

It doesn't matter if I navigate to the directory where input.scss is located. I get the same error .

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: are you in the correct folder?

Comment: Yeah I should be. Input.scss and output.css should be in sass.dart.js the project folder user_testing_v10/node_modules/sass/

When I navigate to that folder and run "sass input.scss output.css" I still get the same error.